# FloatingActionButton Icon disappear after using hide() function

Tags: android, android-tablayout, floating-action-button

So i have tab layout with 4 fragment inside it, i want my FAB change icon according to selected tab. But the problem is after using `fab.hide()`function the icon is disappear. [this is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYbrh.gif)

here is my code:

```
private void fabSettings() {
    mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int position = tab.getPosition();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    mFab.hide();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mFab.show();
                    mFab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_comment_white_24dp);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mFab.show();
                    mFab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_camera_alt_white_24dp);
                    break;
                default:
                    mFab.show();
                    mFab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_phone_black_white_24dp);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

I want when tab at `index 0` selected the FAB is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add three `FloatingActionButton` in your main activity like below:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_M" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabChat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_chat" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabPerson"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_person"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Now in your `MainActivity.java` use Fab's default functions to hide and show on each tab selection like below :

```
private void animateFab(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fabChat.show();
            fabPerson.hide();
            break;
        case 1:
            fabPerson.show();
            fabChat.hide();
            break;
        case 2:
           fabM.show();
           fabPerson.hide();

        default:
            fabChat.show();
            fabPerson.hide();
            break;
    }
}
```

Call animateFab function as below:

```
TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        animateFab(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
};

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        animateFab(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in the FloatingActionButton class: When calling show(), imageMatrixScale is set to 0. A call to setImageResource() then just displays blank. It works before calling show().

The bug has been introduced in the design lib 28.0.0, it was working on v27.1.1. Downgrade to 27.1.1

Hope it will work.

Comment: I'm using androidx, so it's didn't have design lib. what should i do?

Comment: mFab.show(); use this after  mFab.setImageResource();

Comment: this is what i get now https://media.giphy.com/media/IffnxQ84l6ENmQAgLE/giphy.gif

Comment: Welcome . If my answer helps you just accept it . And if  you face any problem you can follow my next answer . I am also posting it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setVisibility` to hide and show the View.

```
mFab.setVisibility(View.GONE); // To hide
mFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // To show
```

Comment: I got an error when using setVisibility. "VisibilityAwareImageButton.setVisibility can only be called from the same library group (groupId=com.google.android.material)"